# Testing the cursor position in a content editable div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, contenteditable

I'm working on a selection library for a project. The library has functions to move the cursor Left, Right, insert the cursor into a specific position, etc. These functions are methods of a class called `Selection` which takes the `id` of a contentEditable div or the div itself when initiated. Like this

```js
const selection = new Selection('editor') 
//or
cosnt editor = document.querySelector('#editor')
const selection = new Selection(editor)
```

I have a function called moveCursorLeft

```js
moveCursorLeft() {
    if (!this.selection || !this.selection?.anchorNode) return;
    const { anchorNode, anchorOffset } = this.selection;
    if (anchorOffset > 0) {
      this.selection.collapse(anchorNode, anchorOffset - 1);
    } else {
      const childrenArray = Array.from(this.editor.children);
      const index = childrenArray.findIndex(
        (child) => child.firstChild === anchorNode
      );

      const prevNode = childrenArray[index - 1];

      if (
        prevNode &&
        prevNode.firstChild &&
        prevNode.firstChild.nodeValue?.length
      ) {
        this.selection.collapse(
          prevNode.firstChild,
          prevNode.firstChild.nodeValue.length - 1
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

This function moves the cursor to the left by one letter and as you can see on the first line of this function I'm checking if `this.selection` exists or not if not then I'm simply stopping the execution by returning (`this.selection` is the selection API which you get like this `window.getSelection()`)

I'm trying to write a test for this method but the problem is that the test run in a node Environment where We don't have access to the window object or the document object because of which the `moveCursorLeft` method stops the execution on the first line since there is no selection object

I'm Willing to change the code inside my function to make the test work

NOTE: I'm using jest and react-testing-library for testing and I'm using typescript

Comment: Why don't you use an front-end testing framework like [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/)?

Comment: I want to do unit testing and I think cypress only supports E2E testing